# Loop through each cell in a table

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a table to loop through. If the active cell contains a 1, then, in a cell outside of the table, the column heading is returned and put into a comma separated list.

I am looking for that loop to continue all the way across the first row cell by cell, and comma separated list to build with each TRUE return.

Once the loop hits the end of the row I need it to drop down to the next row and continue the same process (but creating its own comma separated list for those that returned true in row 2).

Comment: Write what you can so far and show us what you have. People are much more likely to help you here if you have some code written and have a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Ill give it a shot

Comment: [Have you tried anything](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: No I did not know where to start really. Didn't realize this site was for more advanced users.

Comment: It's not that SO is for more advanced users - it's for helping to edit existing code/troubleshoot.  It's not a "how can I do this" type site, but rather "I tried this, but it didn't work, why?" where the user has already put in some effort/attempts.  I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more insight.  We're more than willing to help the most novice of novices.  Try looking around and cobble some code together. Using the macro recorder is a great place to start.

Comment: I recommend that you (in a first step) record the things you want Excel to do for you with the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, I'd recommend reading this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Afterwards you should be set to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice on something you have attempted to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll help you! (Hopefully)

```
Dim x, y as Integer
x = 1
y = 1

For y = 1 To 100
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x) = "1" Then
      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) & x & "/" & y
      Else
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) & ", " & x & "/" & y
      End If
   End If
   If y = 100 And x < 100 Then
      y = 1
      x = x + 1
   End If
Next y
```

Because you are new to VBA I'll tell you that `"Sheet(n)"` depends on the language your are using your excel with (English, German, Spanish). Hope that's what you want. :)

Next Code based on your recent comment:

```
Dim y, x as Integer
Dim aString as String

y = 2
x = 1

For y = 2 To 100
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x) = "1" Then
        aString = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, x)
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) & aString
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) & ", " & aString
        End If
    End If
    If y = 100 And x <> 100 Then
        y = 2
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next y
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it! Unfortunately when I plug this into my sheet I am left with a "Run0time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Nevermind, found it. My bad! Also: this code only loop trough the first 100x100 Cells. If you want more just change the values (1000 instead of 100..)

Comment: Okay this ran now but still not quite right. This is creating a comma sepparated list in Sheet 2 cell (1,1) of what appears to be the location of the "1" in the table. What I am looking for is is the cell has a "1" , then the top row of that column (a string) is put into a comma seperated list. Each row of the table should have its own comma seperated list by the end; filled with the various column headings that returned "yes" due to the 1 being there.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense or is too much I really appreciate the help regardless!

Comment: @K.Wrigley : Please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) the answer and thereby closing it. This will indicate to other users that (a) this post does not require their attention anymore and (b) if someone is looking for a solution to a particular problem then this post will show up as a question with a working solution.